# Git on ubuntu machine with windows client

Tags: git, ssh, passwords

I keep getting an annoying popup that keeps asking me for a git password while accessing my git repo from another machine.I have no git password set up..Have referred various guides to setup git and have gone through the ssh pub/pri key setup.Any help would be appreciated

Regards,
Manish Narang

Comment: It sounds like you haven't set up the public and private key correctly then. Have you definitely configured it in your Windows client? Can you ssh into the machine with your key without a password? Have you got the permissions correct on the authorized_keys on the server?

Answer (score 2):

You didn't specify how you are accessing the repo, but I would suspect something like: `git clone ssh://machine.name.something/path/to/repo`

If this is the case, then what you are being asked is ssh password (your normal machine login password). If you want to make a public repo follow this tutorial: http://book.git-scm.com/4_setting_up_a_public_repository.html

Comment: I forgot to type the `ssh://`. No wonder it cannot connect.  Thanks a lot.